# Web Essentials not showing in Browser

Tags: web-essentials

After the weekend, web essentials doesn't show in the browser anymore. However building Less files, CSS autosync, etc is still working, just this great bar stays hidden.

I searched google it, and it is not just hidden, it's not rendered in the DOM, only

```
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"5c9092ee0b964487b663037c2de3f322"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:1216/d155929549b34e279886e90ecc111382/browserLink" async="async"></script>
```

How can I make the bar visible again / which additional information can I porovide to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe you have hidden it by mistake try pressing `Ctrl`

From the [docs](http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink)

> If you don't care to see the menu all the time, check this checkbox to make it be invisible by default. To toggle visibility of the menu, just click the Ctrl key in the browser.

Comment: yeah, that's a common problem, but it wasn't in my case. Reinstalling Web essentials solved it, so I have no idea what coused it... Anyway your answer seems to solve most problems ;)